# Cant figure out how to create a 'basic' HOC for a react / NextJS application

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have built an application that works well, but i now need to add some logic into each page that checks to see if the user has a subscription and if they do then send them to payment page to make a payment.

I have a hook (using SWR) that gets me the user session and within the hook it returns a boolean for isSubscribed. I intend to use this.

```
const session = useSession();

if(session.isLoading) {
   return <></>;
}

if(!session.isSubscribed) {
   /* redirect the user*/
} 

return (
  <p>HTML of the page / component</p>
)
```

An above example is what i currently do. But this solution requires me to copy pasta everytime to the page which obviously i can do, but it's no way efficient. I know that HOC exists and from what i know i an use a HOC to do this. But i have no idea how to write one that would fit this purpose.

As an added benefit, it would be useful to add the session as a prop to the 'new component' so that i dont have to call the hook twice.

Thanks for all and any help.

p.s. i mention it in the title, but i'm using NextJS. Not sure if this has any baring (i dont think it does, but worth mentioning)

Comment: Did you read docs? https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html , there are few examples which you can use, also I would write "high order component example" in google and see how other people write it, sometimes it is a copy-paste but it is good to know the basics

Comment: i did, but i'm just not quiet getting there with understanding it all.  will try again. other than that any gotchas?

Comment: are you working on functional or class components ?

Comment: functional, i think that's why i couldnt get to grips with the documentation (which i hae just re-read and still confused)

Comment: In functional ones it is better to use custom hooks - they are more readable and easy to create, you can check them here - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html . It looks really hard but believe me it is really easy to understand, just check docs and watch one video on youtube or something

Comment: maybe i'm more confused, i mention in the question that i have a custom hook that gets the user session using SWR, but to do what i want where i need to check for subscribed (in some not all cases) then i need to do the logic as described. Hence why i'm looking at a HOC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a wrapper HOC such as following;

```
const withSession = (Component: NextComponentType<NextPageContext, any, {}>) => {
  const Session = (props: any) => {
    const session = useSession();

    if (session.isLoading) {
      return <>Loading..</>
    }
    else {
      return <Component {...props} />
    }
  };

  // Copy getInitial props so it will run as well
  if (Component.getInitialProps) {
    Session.getInitialProps = Component.getInitialProps;
  }

  return Session;
};
```

And to use it in your page or component, you can simply do like;

```
const UserDetailPage: React.FC = (props) => {
  // ...
  // component's body
  return (<> HI </>);
};

export default withSession(UserDetailPage);
```

Comment: This is exactly what i needed, athough, the types cause an error in VSCode `Argument of type '(props: PageProps) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NextComponentType<NextPageContext, any, {}>'.`

Comment: just trying to figure that out atm, but functionally this is great and has really allowed me to clean up a load of copy pasta

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem doesn't necessary require a HOC, but can be solved with a regular component composition. Depending on your actual use case, it may or may not be a simpler solution.

We could implement a `Session` component that would leverage the `useSession` hook and conditionally render components passed via the `children` prop:

```
const Session = props => {
    const { isLoading } = useSession();
    if (isLoading) {
        return "Loading...";
    }

    return props.children;
};
```

Then nest the `Page` component into the `Session`:

```
const GuardedPage: React.FC<PageProps> = props => {
    return (
        <Session>
            <Page {...props} />
        </Session>
    );
};
```

I see the question has already been answered, just wanted to suggest an alternative. One of the benefits of this approach is that we can wrap an arbitrary tree into the `Session`, and not just the `Page`.

Comment: I think this is a good alternative. However, from my perspective this is also a HOC.

Comment: This is probably a matter of terminology, but my understanding is that a higher-order component should either take a component or return a component (or both). This is precisely what `withSession` from the accepted answer does, which makes it a HOC. But here the `Session` component takes an *element* via the `children` prop and returns an *element*, so from my perspective it's just a regular react component.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to return a page loading screen component and direct the user to the appropriate page based on thier subscription status? or isLoading handles one event and isSubscribed handles another?

Let's define (HOC) higher order component for the sake of your problem. By using HOC, logic can be modularized and redistributed throughout components. This HOC your creating should have the capability to call different methods on a single data source or one method to be applied across multiple components. For instance say you have an API component with 5 end points (login, subscribe, logout, unsubsubscribe) the HOC should have the ability to utilize any of the endpoints from any other component you use it in. HOC is used to create an abstraction that will allow you to define logic in a single place.

Your code calls one singular method to check if the session is in use of display the content of a page based on user subscription and page loading. Without seeing the components you are trying to use I can not determine the state that needs to be passed? but I will give it shot.

```
const session = useSession();

if(session.isLoading) {
   return <></>;
}

if(!session.isSubscribed) {
   /* redirect the user*/
} 

return (
  <p>HTML of the page / component</p>
)
```

First thing I see wrong in above code as a use case for an HOC component you have no export statement to share with other components. Also, why use 2 return statements for isLoading unless both conditions need to be checked (isLoading & isSubscribed) also, are these conditional statements depended on each other or seprate functions that can be called separately from another source? if  you posted more of your code or the components you are pasting this into it would help?

To use this as an HOC in NEXT is essentially the same as react.
Dependant logic

```
const session = useSession(props);
// ad constructor and state logic 
... 

if(session.isLoading) {
   return this.setState({isLoading: true});
} else { 
  return this.setState({isSubscribed: false});
}
```

Separate logic

```
const session = useSession(props);
// ad constructor and state logic 
... 

isLoading () => { 
  return this.setState({isLoading: true});
} 


isSubscribed() => { 
  return this.setState({isSubscribed: true});
}
```

or something like this that uses routes...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

export const HOC = { 

  isState: false, 

  isSubscribed(props) {
    this.isState = false;
    setTimeout(props, 100);
  },
  isLoading(props) {
    this.isState = true;
    setTimeout(props, 100);
  }
};

export const AuthRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest}) => { 

  return (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
     HOC.isAuthenticated === true ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to='/' /> 
  )}/>
)};


}
```

If you could share more of you code it would be more helpful? or one of the  components you are having to copy and paste from your original HOC code. I would be easier than stabbing in the dark to assist in your problem but I hope this helps!

Cheers!